# How to post data to a local route using fetch in flask/react.js?

Tags: reactjs, flask, post, fetch

I am trying to send the contents of a flashcard to a backend route http://127.0.0.1:5000/post onClick and it works when I send the data to webhook.site but when I change it to http://127.0.0.1:5000/post I get the error " question = data['question' TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable ". Here is the code for the fetch request:
async function postData() {

```
    try {

        let result = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/post', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',

            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                key: `${Date.now()}`,
                question: flashcard.question,
                answer: flashcard.answer,
                options: flashcard.options
            })
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the backend route in flask:

```
@app.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post():
#save data to db
data = request.get_json()

question = data['question']
answer = data['answer']
options = data['options']
key = data['key']

return jsonify({'question' : question, 'answer' : answer, 'options' : options, 'key' : key})


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

I get that the error is stating that "data" has no value which I assume means it's not recieving the JSON objects that I'm posting. It's weird because it works perfectly when I use a webhook.site url. can anyone help? thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your content is not a valid json request. If that is the case then content will be equal to None(not subscriptable).

Try to debug how data looks in flask and based on that you will know if its valid json.